# How to add an empty map type column to DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a new map type column to a dataframe, like this:

```
|-- cMap: map (nullable = true)
|    |-- key: string
|    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I tried the code:

```scala
df.withColumn("cMap", lit(null).cast(MapType)).printSchema
```

The error is:

> :132: error: overloaded method value cast with alternatives:
> (to: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column 
> (to: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
> cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.types.MapType.type)

Is there another way to cast the new column to Map or MapType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike other types, `MapType` isn't an object you can just use as-is (it's not an object extending `DataType`), you have to call `MapType.apply(...)` which expects the key and value types as arguments (and returns an instance of the `MapType` *class*):

```
df.withColumn("cMap", lit(null).cast(MapType(StringType, StringType)))
```

Comment: This inserts a `null`, not an empty map `{}`, or what am I missing?

Comment: @Lou_Ds looking at the OP's code, I'm assuming that's exactly what they needed - a column with the right type and null values. The fact the OP _accepted_ this answer confirms this.

Comment: Rmk: what this does is create a column containing `null` values casted to be able to contain `Map[String, String]` as it would be mentionned in the Dataframe schema.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, finally I found solution:

```
df.withColumn("cMap", typedLit(Map.empty[String, String]))
```

From ScalaDocs for `typedLit`:

> The difference between this function and [[lit]] is that this function can handle parameterized scala types e.g.: List, Seq and Map.

Answer (score 1):

You can be as much Scala as in the other answer(s) or use a little trick with *stringified* types.

```
val withMapCol = df.withColumn("cMap", lit(null) cast "map<string, string>")
scala> withMapCol.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- cMap: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

---

You can use any type that Spark SQL supports this way (that you can see in the code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L621-L625)):

```
dataType
    : complex=ARRAY '<' dataType '>'                            #complexDataType
    | complex=MAP '<' dataType ',' dataType '>'                 #complexDataType
    | complex=STRUCT ('<' complexColTypeList? '>' | NEQ)        #complexDataType
    | identifier ('(' INTEGER_VALUE (',' INTEGER_VALUE)* ')')?  #primitiveDataType
```

Comment: Any way to create a static MAP field using the same trick? I want to create a column with MAP type like this {"field1" -> "fieldname"}

Comment: Spark 2.0 +

val df1 = df.withColumn("newcol",map(lit("field1"),lit("fieldName1")))

scala> df1.show()
+---+--------------------+
|  a|              newcol|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|Map(field1 -> fie...|
|  2|Map(field1 -> fie...|
|  3|Map(field1 -> fie...|
|  4|Map(field1 -> fie...|
+---+--------------------+

Answer (score 0):

```
map().cast("map<string,string>")
```

To me, `lit(null).cast(...)` was not an option, because `map_concat` with non-empty map returned null... while the above worked well.